# Lack of wireless connection: Ubuntu 22.04.2 and Asus pce-ac88

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, asus

I'm using Ubuntu for over the year and my WiFi worked correctly. Today, when I turned on my PC, there wasn't any wireless connection at all (I didn't change anything or install some new software). I'm using Asus pce-ac88 and it works correctly on second OS (windows 10). I was using Ubuntu 20.04 at that time.

Right now I'm working on Ethernet cable and I updated Ubuntu on 22.04, but still no WiFi.
I also work on Ubuntu with dual boot if it matters (Windows 10).

Wireless info: https://pastebin.com/54rMM78m

Any advices what can i do except reinstalling Ubuntu?

EDIT:

```
sudo dmesg | grep brcm

[    4.130189] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    4.238791] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie for chip BCM4366/4
[    4.239334] brcmfmac 0000:06:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie.MSI-MS-7917.bin failed with error -2
[    4.245787] brcmfmac 0000:06:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie.MSI-MS-7917.txt failed with error -2
[    4.245802] brcmfmac 0000:06:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[    5.126527] brcmfmac 0000:06:00.0: brcmf_pcie_init_ringbuffers: invalid max_flowrings(264)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep brcm` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Added output. Welcome!

Comment: Please see: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/104pqv9/no_wifi_since_kernel_update_yesterday/ The logs shows the exact same error; *brcmf_pcie_init_ringbuffers: invalid max_flowrings(264)*. I believe that a kernel update brought about the error. Can you boot into an earlier kernel at the GRUB menu and does the wireless work there?

Comment: I used earlier version (5.15.0-67 instead of 5.15.0-69) and it works!

Comment: I suggest that you stick with 5.15.0-67 and file a bug report: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Sure, thanks for the help!

Comment: @chili555 Can you post the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/104pqv9/no_wifi_since_kernel_update_yesterday/ The log shows the exact same error; *brcmf_pcie_init_ringbuffers: invalid max_flowrings(264)*. I believe that a kernel update brought about the error.

When you booted into an earlier kernel version; specifically 5.15.0-67, the wireless works as expected.

I recommend that you stay on -67 and file a bug report: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs